# angucomplete-alt tag 'required' in a form

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, required

Having the below directive inside form tag, but not sure why field-required is not working and form is getting submitted.

```
<form>
    <angucomplete-alt id="fromStationInput"
          placeholder="Enter from location"
          pause="100"
          selected-object="fromSelected"
          local-data="mapToArray"
          search-fields="fromLocation"
          local-search="localSearch"
          title-field="cityName"
          minlength="1"
          input-class="input-text full-width" ng-model="fromLocation" match-   class="highlight"
  field-required="true"
  input-name="cityName"/>
</form>
```